# Is there a way to make an Italian Windows 7 Starter to speak Spanish?

Tags: windows-7, windows, language, language-pack

We have this brand-new Windows 7 Starter netbook with Italian language and we'd like to have it in Spanish instead.

MS will not let me download and install a Language Pack and neither a Language Interface Pack.
I'm ok with reinstalling Windows if that matters.

Short of buying a new Windows 7 license (arch), can the current OEM license be used for a different language, or can it be changed to a new license for the new language? Or anything else?

Thanks.

Comment: In the windows XP days OEM licenses seemed to be locked to the specific windows version the vendor installed, however I've re-installed computers with windows 7 retail disks using the OEM key. There is a chance it will allow you to install the spanish version of W7 Starter with the OEM, but I'm not sure if starter versions have any restrictions on that.  If you have a copy available it's a quick process to try it out at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows language packs can only be used with Windows 7 Enterprise or Windows 7 Ultimate.

Therefore you won't succeed with a Windows 7 Starter edition. You will have to buy a Spanish Windows 7 version or learn Italian...

Even if it would work to activate an Spanish Windows 7 installation using the Italian license key it would illegal because the license key and the installation DVD are a bundle that can not be used otherwise.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972813/en-us

Answer (score 2):

As far as i'm aware (90% sure) OEM licences are only for the country/language they are issued/bought in.